# How to return identical values for identical query parameters in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got some PHP that builds and executes a query using PDO. The query is getting usernames and user images from a `users` table, and ID parameters are added to it from an array in a PHP for loop. Thus, the query looks something like this once it's built:

`SELECT username, image FROM users WHERE id=4 OR id=2 OR id=16 OR id=8 OR id=9;`

The PHP expects as many rows to be returned from the query as there were ID values plugged into it. This works just fine when all the IDs are unique, but when there are identical IDs in the query, MySQL (efficiently) returns only one row for each unique ID, as below.

`SELECT username, image FROM users WHERE id=4 OR id=2 OR id=2 OR id=4 OR id=2;`

This query would only return 2 rows, one for the user with ID 4 and one for user ID 2. Like I said, the application expects as many rows returned as ID parameters submitted, so this is a problem. Is there a different way to phrase my SQL query to force it to return identical rows?

Comment: You could run the same query multiple times in a loop.  Or better yet handle the issue in php as it is probably better code design

Comment: try with `WHERE id IN(2, 4, 8, 9, 16)`

Comment: @ThiagoFrança Are you sure you have read the question?

Comment: why would you have identical id's passed to it? if its data for the same user then why not just duplicate that in php?

Comment: Shouldn't have tagged it PHP, my mistake. It's really just a SQL question. I'm aware that I could change the way the application handles things. I was only wondering whether there was some SQL clause that would force number of rows returned to match number of parameters in a query.

Comment: writing one select for each id and after, union all theirs,like
`SELECT username, image FROM users WHERE id=4 LIMIT 2
UNION 
SELECT username, image FROM users WHERE id=2 LIMIT 3;`
use [array_count_values](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to know the frequency of every value in array.

Comment: this shouldn't just be a sql question, as writing a sql query to do this would be nasty and not perform well. you should aim to get the stuff from the unique people and then duplicate it in php or any other language... would make your performance much faster

Comment: Thanks y'all. I'm going to handle the problem with PHP, as I see that there's not a good way to do what I need with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your application refine input data by taking out duplicates. Thus, only two ids will be sent and two lines will satisfy the expectation.

Comment: I know that I could refine the application; the question was whether there's a way to force MySQL to return identical rows from such a query.

Comment: the question is whether there's any sane reason to do that

Comment: Responses like this are the reason newer programmers are afraid to ask simple questions.

Comment: I dunno; one of the best responses to a question is "Why?" Why do you want this to happen? Sometimes that leads to a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array, taking only the uniques values, and then use IN in your query:

```
<?php
$array = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
$array = array_unique( $array );

// when only numeric values
$values = implode(",", $array );

// when strings
//$values = "'" . implode("','", $array ) . "'";

$query = 'SELECT username, image FROM users WHERE id IN( ' . $values . ')';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the frequency of each value in array. 
After, make a loop and write one query with limit for each id, then, union all query's.

```
<?php
$array = array(2, 4, 2, 2, 4);
$values = array_count_values($array);

$query = array();

foreach ($values as $id => $frequency)
{
    $query[] = "SELECT username, image FROM users WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT {$frequency}";
}

$query = implode(" UNION ", $query);
```